# How to find out if (the source code of) a function contains a call to a method from a specific module?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, inspect

Let's say, I have a bunch of functions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` and I want to find out if they call any method from the `random` module:

```
def a():
    pass

def b():
    import random

def c():
    import random
    random.randint(0, 1)

def d():
    import random as ra
    ra.randint(0, 1)

def e():
    from random import randint as ra
    ra(0, 1)
```

I want to write a function `uses_module` so I can expect these assertions to pass:

```
assert uses_module(a) == False
assert uses_module(b) == False
assert uses_module(c) == True
assert uses_module(d) == True
assert uses_module(e) == True
```

(`uses_module(b)` is `False` because `random` is only imported but never one of its methods called.)

I can't modify `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`. So I thought it might be possible to use `ast` for this and walk along the function's code which I get from `inspect.getsource`. **But I'm open to any other proposals, this was only an idea how it could work.**

This is as far as I've come with `ast`:

```
def uses_module(function):
    import ast
    import inspect
    nodes = ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(function)))
    for node in nodes:
        print(node.__dict__)
```

Comment: I imagine there would be a path forward using `mock` and `assert_called` to mock functions found in the ast of a type. will think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `random` module with a mock object, providing custom attribute access and hence intercepting function calls. Whenever one of the functions tries to import (from) `random` it will actually access the mock object. The mock object can also be designed as a context manager, handing back the original `random` module after the test.

```
import sys


class Mock:
    import random
    random = random

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.modules['random'] = self
        self.method_called = False
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.modules['random'] = self.random

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def mock(*args, **kwargs):
            self.method_called = True
            return getattr(self.random, name)
        return mock


def uses_module(func):
    with Mock() as m:
        func()
        return m.method_called
```

---

#### Variable module name

A more flexible way, specifying the module's name, is achieved by:

```
import importlib
import sys


class Mock:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.module = importlib.import_module(name)

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.modules[self.name] = self
        self.method_called = False
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.modules[self.name] = self.module

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def mock(*args, **kwargs):
            self.method_called = True
            return getattr(self.module, name)
        return mock


def uses_module(func):
    with Mock('random') as m:
        func()
        return m.method_called
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a work in progress, but perhaps it will spark a better idea. I am using the types of nodes in the AST to attempt to assert that a module is imported and some function it provides is used.

I have added what may be the necessary pieces to determine that this is the case to a `checker` defaultdict which can be evaluated for some set of conditions, but I am not using all key value pairs to establish an assertion for your use cases.

```
def uses_module(function):
    """
    (WIP) assert that a function uses a module
    """
    import ast
    import inspect
    nodes = ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(function)))
    checker = defaultdict(set)
    for node in nodes:
        if type(node) in [ast.alias, ast.Import, ast.Name, ast.Attribute]:
            nd = node.__dict__
            if type(node) == ast.alias:
                checker['alias'].add(nd.get('name'))
            if nd.get('name') and nd.get('asname'):
                checker['name'].add(nd.get('name'))
                checker['asname'].add(nd.get('asname'))
            if nd.get('ctx') and nd.get('attr'):
                checker['attr'].add(nd.get('attr'))
            if nd.get('id'):
                checker['id'].add(hex(id(nd.get('ctx'))))
            if nd.get('value') and nd.get('ctx'):
                checker['value'].add(hex(id(nd.get('ctx'))))

    # print(dict(checker)) for debug

    # This check passes your use cases, but probably needs to be expanded
    if checker.get('alias') and checker.get('id'):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place a mock `random.py` in your local (test) directory containing the following code:

```
# >= Python 3.7.
def __getattr__(name):
    def mock(*args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError(f'{name}: {args}, {kwargs}')  # For example.
    return mock


# <= Python 3.6.
class Wrapper:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def mock(*args, **kwargs):
            raise RuntimeError('{}: {}, {}'.format(name, args, kwargs))  # For example.
        return mock

import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = Wrapper()
```

Then you simply test your functions as follows:

```
def uses_module(func):
    try:
        func()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print(err)
        return True
    return False
```

This works because instead of importing the builtin `random` module it will go for the mock module which emulates [custom attribute access](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) and hence can intercept the function calls.

If you don't want to interrupt the functions by raising an exception you can still use the same approach, by importing the original `random` module in the mock module (modifying `sys.path` appropriately) and then falling back on the original functions.